# How to create a .ics file from the data kept in a local database?Please help

Tags: c#

i have been trying to create an ics file from the data kept at the local database Please Help

Comment: What problem are you having?  It is a pretty simple file format:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar#Core_object

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the open source [DDay.iCal](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/) library to do that and I have heard good things about this library:

> DDay.iCal is an iCalendar class library written in C# and based on the [RFC 2445](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt) standard. It parses files in the iCalendar format and provides an object-oriented interface to iCalendar components: Event, Todo, TimeZone, Journal, FreeBusy, and Alarm.

There is also another open source library called [ICalendar](http://icalendar.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex which doesn't have a release yet, but you can download/check out the [source code](http://icalendar.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest):

> iCalendar is a standard (RFC 2445) for calendar data exchange. The standard is sometimes referred to as "iCal", which also is the name of the Apple, Inc. calendar program (see iCal) that provides one of the implementations of the standard.